# How to take data from a file and replace the predefined array in the Sudoku game

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, sudoku

Inside the main method an array is already defined, i want to take that array from a file by using the scanner class and the user wil enter the name of the file.

This is what i am trying to do i am trying to pass the data of the file into an string and then i am trying to pass the string into an integer array

```
package theSuDoKuSolver;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class BackTracking
{ 
public static boolean isSafe(int[][] board, int row, int col, int num)  
{ 

    for (int d = 0; d < board.length; d++)  
    { 
        // if the number we are trying to  
        // place is already present in  
        // that row, return false; 

        if (board[row][d] == num)  
        { 
            return false; 
        }   
    } 

    // column has the unique numbers (column-clash) 
    for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++) 
    { 
        // if the number we are trying to 
        // place is already present in 
        // that column, return false; 

        if (board[r][col] == num) 
        { 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 

    // corresponding square has 
    // unique number (box-clash) 
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(board.length); 
    int boxRowStart = row - row % sqrt; 
    int boxColStart = col - col % sqrt; 

    for (int r = boxRowStart; 
             r < boxRowStart + sqrt; r++)  
    { 
        for (int d = boxColStart;  
                 d < boxColStart + sqrt; d++)  
        { 
            if (board[r][d] == num)  
            { 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

        // if there is no clash, it's safe 
    return true; 
} 

public static boolean solveSudoku(int[][] board, int n)  
{ 
    int row = -1; 
    int col = -1; 
    boolean isEmpty = true; 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)  
        { 
            if (board[i][j] == 0)  
            { 
                row = i; 
                col = j; 

                // we still have some remaining 
                // missing values in Sudoku 
                isEmpty = false;  
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        if (!isEmpty) 
        { 
            break; 
        } 
    } 

    // no empty space left 
    if (isEmpty)  
    { 
        return true; 
    } 

    // else for each-row backtrack 
    for (int num = 1; num <= n; num++) 
    { 
        if (isSafe(board, row, col, num)) 
        { 
            board[row][col] = num; 
            if (solveSudoku(board, n))  
            { 
                // print(board, n); 
                return true; 
            }  
            else
            { 
                board[row][col] = 0; // replace it 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
} 

public static void print(int[][] board, int N) 
{ 
    // we got the answer, just print it 
    for (int r = 0; r < N; r++) 
    { 
        for (int d = 0; d < N; d++) 
        { 
            System.out.print(board[r][d]); 
            System.out.print(" "); 
        } 
        System.out.print("\n"); 

        if ((r + 1) % (int) Math.sqrt(N) == 0)  
        { 
            System.out.print(""); 
        } 
    } 
} 

// Driver Code 
@SuppressWarnings("resource")

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 

   File file = new File("Evil532");
   String content = null;
   try {
        content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int[][] board = new int[9][9];  

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(content);

        int i=0; int r=0;
            while(sc.hasNext()) {
                String st = sc.next();
                for(i=0;i<st.length();i++)
                    board[r][i]=st.charAt(i);               
                r++;
            }

//  System.out.println(content);
//  System.out.println(board);


//    int[][] board = new int[][] 
//    { 
//            {3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0}, 
//            {5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
//            {0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1}, 
//            {0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0}, 
//            {9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5}, 
//            {0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0}, 
//            {1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0}, 
//            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4}, 
//            {0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0} 
//    }; 


    int N = board.length; 

    if (solveSudoku(board, N)) 
    { 
        print(board, N); // print solution 
    }  
    else
    { 
        System.out.println("No solution"); 
    } 
} 
}
```

```
// The file has some data like 
005007900
700050148
000000000
009304000
140000300
000010002
003070020
006023500
020600007
```

This is what I am trying to do but the answer is coming wrong

Expected Result

```
3 1 6 5 7 8 4 9 2 
5 2 9 1 3 4 7 6 8 
4 8 7 6 2 9 5 3 1 
2 6 3 4 1 5 9 8 7 
9 7 4 8 6 3 1 2 5 
8 5 1 7 9 2 6 4 3 
1 3 8 9 4 7 2 5 6 
6 9 2 3 5 1 8 7 4 
7 4 5 2 8 6 3 1 9
```

This is the expected result that shows that the array is solved with proper solution.

Actual Result

```
48 48 53 48 48 55 57 48 48 
55 48 48 48 53 48 49 52 56 
48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 
48 48 57 51 48 52 48 48 48 
49 52 48 48 48 48 51 48 48 
48 48 48 48 49 48 48 48 50 
48 48 51 48 55 48 48 50 48 
48 48 54 48 50 51 53 48 48 
48 50 48 54 48 48 48 48 55
```

The answer is showing wromg result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here: `board[r][i] = st.charAt(i);`

You are assigning the `char` value to an `int`. So `i` is `48` for the `'0'` value. You should convert the `char` value to the correct `int`. For example use this:

```
board[r][i] = st.charAt(i) - '0';
```

To get a complete view of the ascii numbers you can look here: https://www.ascii-code.com/

Alternatively you can use this:

```
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String[] numbers = sc.next().split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        board[r][i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
    r++;
}
```

Beside that your code to read the file is not very clear I would suggest using something like this:

```
int[][] board = new int[9][9];
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/file")));
String line;
int lineNumber = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] numbers = line.split("");
    for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < numbers.length; columnNumber++)
        board[lineNumber][columnNumber] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[columnNumber]);
    lineNumber++;
}
br.close();
```